# How to automatically fill matrices in array from existing set of values in R via a loop?

Tags: arrays, r, loops, matrix

I'm trying to automate the creation of an array in R where the matrix cells are filled from existings sets of values. For example,

I have 3 sets with 6 values each.

```
valuecos = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
directcos = c(10,20,30,40,50,60)
pricecos = c(100, 200, 300, 400,500,600)
```

What I want is the following array

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   10  100
[2,]    2   20  200
[3,]    3   30  300

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4   40  400
[2,]    5   50  500
[3,]    6   60  600
```

Right now, I doing this manually

```
lag1<-matrix(c(valuecos[1],valuecos[2],valuecos[3],directcos[1],directcos[2],directcos[3],pricecos[1],pricecos[2],pricecos[3]), nrow=3, ncol=3)
lag2<-matrix(c(valuecos[4],valuecos[5],valuecos[6],directcos[4],directcos[5],directcos[6],pricecos[4],pricecos[5],pricecos[6]), nrow=3, ncol=3)
matrices <- list(lag1, lag2)
matlist <- array(data = do.call(cbind, matrices), dim = c(dim(matrices[[1]]), length(matrices)));
```

But the array may get bigger, so may the number of sets and values per set so I want to automate the whole array creation via a loop to avoid mistakes. I'm not a big expert in loops, so I only got as far as below with a lot of code still missing. I assume I'll need an outer loop for the number of matrices t in my array and then an inner loop where I can fill the individual matrix cells out of the value set?

```
lags = t
nrow = a
nrow = b

matlist = array(NA,c(a,b,t))
for (i in 1:t){
  matlist[,,i] = ????

lag = matrix(NA, nrow = a, ncol=b)
for (r in 1:a){
  for (c in 1:b){
    lag[,,] <- (valuecos[r]... ???)
  }
}
}
```

It would be great if someone could help me further along. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you insist on a loop?  If the goal is to transform these data into an array, you can do it directly (although admittedly it always takes me a few tries to get the order right ...)

```
valuecos = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
directcos = c(10,20,30,40,50,60)
pricecos = c(100, 200, 300, 400,500,600)
```

Put everything together:

```
M <- cbind(valuecos,directcos,pricecos)
```

Put it into an array: use *named* dimnames to hurt your brain less when trying to rearrange/permute.

```
a1 <- array(M,dim=c(3,2,3),dimnames=list(D1=1:3,D2=c("a","b"),
                                         D3=c("v","d","p")))
```

Now permute:

```
a2 <- aperm(a1,c("D1","D3","D2"))
## , , D2 = a
## 
##    D3
## D1  v  d   p
##   1 1 10 100
##   2 2 20 200
##   3 3 30 300
## 
## , , D2 = b
## 
##    D3
## D1  v  d   p
##   1 4 40 400
##   2 5 50 500
##   3 6 60 600
```

Comment: I'm not sure this gives me an array, where I can than later again extract values from, as in dd[1,1,1] = 1?